# Can we express any matrix as an outer product expansion?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Suppose  $XY$ is an $m $ by $n$ matrix, where $X$ is a $m$ by  $k$ matrix and $Y$ is a $k$ by $n$ matrix. $y_i$ are the columns of $Y$ and $x_i$ are the columns of $X$. How do we know that $XY=\Sigma^{k}_{i=1}x_{i}y_{i}^{T}$ ?

I made an attempt to justify this.

$$XY = [x_1|x_2|..|x_k][y_1|y_2|..|y_n]$$

$$XY = X[y_1,y_2,..,y_n]=[Xy_1|Xy_2|..|Xy_n]$$

$$XY=[\Sigma_{i=1}^{k} y_{i1} x_{i}|\Sigma_{i=1}^{k} y_{i2} x_{i}|..|\Sigma_{i=1}^{k} y_{ik} x_{i}|0_{k+1}|...|0_n]$$

I am stuck here

Comment: This does not make sense. If $x_i$ and $y_i$ are columns of $X$ and $Y$, the sum of their outer products is certainly not $XY$ (in most cases); just check what is the size of $XY$ ($m\times n$) and of $x_iy_i^T$ ($m\times k$). $XY$ is a sum of the outer products of the *columns* of $X$ and the *rows* of $Y$ though.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel You are correct. $y_i$'s represent the ROWS of the matrix $Y $, NOT THE COLUMNS!! Thank you that cleared a lot of clutter